# Затухание картинки сбоку

Tags: jquery, скрипт, javascript, css

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста. 
Есть картинка с логотипом, нужно сделать, чтобы она постепенно затухала (исчезала), от краёв к центру. Как это можно реализовать? Или, может, есть какой готовы скрипт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Оберните ваш логотип в новый `div` и назначьте ему класс, например `wrapper`
- После логотипа вставьте еще один `div` и назначьте ему класс, например `overlay`
- Абсолютно спозиционируйте `overlay` внутри `wrapper` и задайте ему 100% ширину и высоту.
- Задайте `overlay` css-свойство `pointer-events: none;`, чтобы все клики шли по логотипу под ним.
- С помощью **[ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)** сгенерируйте полупрозрачный градиентный фон для `overlay`